# Interleaving updates of volatile variables (registers)?

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, cpu-registers

I'm writing a C++ template wrapper for GPIOs. For the STM32 I'm using the HAL and LL code as basis. The GPIO initialization comes down to a series of `read register to temp variable` -> `Mask pin specific bits in temp` -> `shift and write pin specific bits in temp` -> `write temp back to register`. The registers are declared `volatile`.

Would it make sense (in terms of reducing overhead / improving performance) to first do all the reads to the volatiles, then all the updates, then all the writes to the volatiles, instead of sequentially, as it is now (in ST's code, for example)? The writes would still be in-order, of course.

So from scenario **A**:

```
uint32_t temp;
temp = struct->reg1;
temp |= ...
temp &= ...
struct->reg1 = temp;
temp = struct->reg2;
temp |= ...
temp &= ...
struct->reg2 = temp;
```

to scenario **B**:

```
uint32_t temp1, temp2;
temp1 = struct->reg1;
temp2 = struct->reg2;
temp1 |= ...
temp1 &= ...
temp2 |= ...
temp2 &= ...
struct->reg1 = temp1;
struct->reg2 = temp2;
```

Scenario B might use a bit (or 4) more memory, but doesn't have to interrupt the main program flow as often I'd expect. Can the code be optimised more in scenario B, for example by combining reads or writes?

Comment: It wouldn't make much difference.  Access to the volatile registers cannot be optimized and the STM has no memory cache...  Scenario A uses a bit less stack space than scenario B, bit that's negligible.  It is also more readable, which is the only thing you have to aim for here.

Comment: In general it might have different behaviour. In the first version you write to `reg1` and then read from `reg2`. The volatile write to `reg1` _may_ affect the value read from `reg2`? Only you can know if this is an actual scenario your code can hit, but it is something to bear in mind.

Comment: Scenario B needs 2 temporary variables, while A needs only 1. So A is a more optimal solution, given that STM32 doesn't have a lot of spare registers to hold the temp values. When in doubt, always check/compare the generated assembly.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy *`STM has no memory cache`* really? Check before posting.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy You wrote about memory cache. Many STM uC do have memory cache. Not if the hardware register addresses are cacheable.

Comment: MikeVine, I was worried about the same, but inferring from the code it shouldn't. What's not present in any code though (not even STs) is any facility for preventing incorrect updates when an there's another update from inside an interrupt for example (not as unlikely as you'd think, each register write controls up to 16 pins).
rustyx register pressure is a good catch, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use BSRR for atomic writes instead of read-modify-write? You can also write a wrapper class for individual pins which could allow you to do something similar to this: `PA10.set();`.

Comment: @Tagli Well, because that's for setting the pin (high/low) state. Which can indeed be updated like that. This is about switching the pin mode. Practical example: Some sensors use one pin for input or output, depending on state. The current wrapper allows multiple 'handles' (shared base template with static members) to share a pin and handle the pin mode changes on the background.

Comment: Okay, in this case R-M-W is unavoidable. What is the uC model BTW?

Comment: @Tagli do you discuss uCs not knowing them at all?

Comment: @Stefan why not simply open drain?

Comment: @0___________ old F1's have different set of GPIO registers compared to other models.

Comment: @Tagli But it does not change too much in our case. CLx registers to confure modes and speeds.

Comment: Generally, Cortex M does not have any form of cache. M7 may optionally have it. STM32 could mean anything though, it just says "32 bit ARM MCU from ST".

Answer (score 1):

It will not make any difference. The code will be exactly same efficient

```
void zoo(uint32_t val1, uint32_t val2)
{
    uint32_t moder = GPIOA -> MODER;
    uint32_t otyper = GPIOA -> OTYPER;
    moder &= val1;
    moder |= val2;
    otyper &= val1;
    otyper |= val2;
    GPIOA -> MODER = moder;
    GPIOA -> OTYPER = otyper;
}

void boo(uint32_t val1, uint32_t val2)
{
    uint32_t val = GPIOA -> MODER;
    val &= val1;
    val |= val2;
    GPIOA -> MODER = val;
    val = GPIOA -> OTYPER;
    val &= val1;
    val |= val2;
    GPIOA -> OTYPER = val;
}
```

And it is not existing problems as you access more than one register of the GPIO only during the initialization. The pin configuration is usually set only at the program startup and sometimes when entering and exiting the low power modes (for example we set pins to be in the analogue mode to consume as less as possible current). Performance is not the first priority at this stage.

Normally you will access only one register:

BSRR - to set pins (but this register is **write only**)
ODR - to set and read what have we set
IDR - actual pin levels (**read only**)

BSRR in some STM micros is split into two registers BRR & BSR but they are also **write only**.

IMO you try to microoptimize something which completely does not require it.

https://godbolt.org/z/xWqWo9

Answer (score 1):

> Would it make sense (in terms of reducing overhead / improving performance) to first do all the reads to the volatiles, then all the updates, then all the writes to the volatiles, instead of sequentially, as it is now (in ST's code, for example)?

So nothing more to do than check it! The following code:

```
// based on code from https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS
#include <stdint.h>
#define __IO volatile
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t CR;
  __IO uint32_t CSR;
} PWR_TypeDef;
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000) /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region */
#define APB1PERIPH_BASE       PERIPH_BASE
#define PWR_BASE              (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x7000)
#define PWR                 ((PWR_TypeDef *) PWR_BASE)

#define  PWR_CR_LPDS                         ((uint16_t)0x0001)     /*!< Low-Power Deepsleep */
#define  PWR_CR_PDDS                         ((uint16_t)0x0002)     /*!< Power Down Deepsleep */
#define  PWR_CR_CWUF                         ((uint16_t)0x0004)     /*!< Clear Wakeup Flag */
#define  PWR_CR_CSBF                         ((uint16_t)0x0008)     /*!< Clear Standby Flag */
#define  PWR_CR_PVDE                         ((uint16_t)0x0010)     /*!< Power Voltage Detector Enable */

#define  PWR_CSR_WUF                         ((uint16_t)0x0001)     /*!< Wakeup Flag */
#define  PWR_CSR_SBF                         ((uint16_t)0x0002)     /*!< Standby Flag */
#define  PWR_CSR_PVDO                        ((uint16_t)0x0004)     /*!< PVD Output */
#define  PWR_CSR_EWUP                        ((uint16_t)0x0100)     /*!< Enable WKUP pin */

void func_separate() {
    // just a meaningless example for testing
    uint32_t temp;
    temp = PWR->CR;
    temp &= PWR_CR_LPDS | PWR_CR_PDDS | PWR_CR_CWUF;
    temp |= PWR_CR_CWUF;
    PWR->CR = temp;
    temp = PWR->CSR;
    temp &= PWR_CSR_WUF | PWR_CSR_SBF;
    temp |= PWR_CSR_PVDO | PWR_CSR_EWUP;
    PWR->CSR = temp;
}

void func_together() {
    uint32_t temp1, temp2;
    temp1 = PWR->CR;
    temp2 = PWR->CSR;
    temp1 &= PWR_CR_LPDS | PWR_CR_PDDS | PWR_CR_CWUF;
    temp1 |= PWR_CR_CWUF;
    temp2 &= PWR_CSR_WUF | PWR_CSR_SBF;
    temp2 |= PWR_CSR_PVDO | PWR_CSR_EWUP;
    PWR->CR = temp1;
    PWR->CSR = temp2;
}
```

[outputs on godbolt with gcc ARM 8.2 `-O3 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3`](https://godbolt.org/z/KExY8b):

```
func_separate:
        ldr     r2, .L3
        ldr     r3, [r2]
        and     r3, r3, #7
        orr     r3, r3, #4
        str     r3, [r2]
        ldr     r3, [r2, #4]
        and     r3, r3, #3
        orr     r3, r3, #260
        str     r3, [r2, #4]
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   1073770496
func_together:
        ldr     r1, .L6
        ldr     r2, [r1]
        ldr     r3, [r1, #4]
        and     r2, r2, #7
        and     r3, r3, #3
        orr     r2, r2, #4
        orr     r3, r3, #260
        str     r2, [r1]
        str     r3, [r1, #4]
        bx      lr
.L6:
        .word   1073770496
```

The only difference is the order of instruction. There is no difference in terms of performance. So `Would it make sense (in terms of reducing overhead / improving performance)` - no.

But it would make sense to prefer the first version in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, it doesn't matter.

Generally speaking though, it is recommended practice not to access individual hardware registers in several lines when it can be avoided. It is good practice to write everything in temporary RAM variables and only read and write to the register once.

This doesn't have so much to do with execution time, but rather that reading & writing hardware registers can come with many side-effects such as clearing flags or affect real time.

Furthermore, stuff like `temp1 |= ... temp1 &= ...` on temporary variables can get easily optimized by the compiler, which is very likely to use CPU register for such rather than stack allocation.

Another thing worth mentioning is that read/writes to hardware registers cannot get optimized or re-sequenced, since they are `volatile` qualified. For this reason you'll want to minimize register accesses to save a tiny bit of execution time, but also to allow the compiler to more efficiently optimize the surrounding code.

Comment: Are you sure about ST register maps? There are no unions in them. Mostly structs & typedefs. Struct members which map to HW registers are defined as *volatile*. HW adresses are pointer-casted to these structs. I had no register related problems when using C++ with STM32.

Comment: @Tagli Hmm I might be confusing it for some other bloatware lib actually. I'll remove that part.